# Correct way to type nullable state when using React's useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having trouble figuring out how to type `useState` function since it returns a tuple. In essence, I have to provide `null` as initial value for `email` i.e. lets assume I can't use empty string here.

I then have `setEmail` function to update this state value, which takes in email as string.

ideally I would like to type my `useState` so it expects email to be either string or null if possible. At the moment it inherits it as only `null`

```
import * as React from "react";

const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ email: null, password: null });

  function setEmail(email: string) {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email }))
  }

  return <p>{state.email}</p>
}
```

Following error is returned for `setEmail` function since `string` in function argument is not valid type for `null` specified in `useState()`

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(prevState: { email: null; password: null; }) => { email: string; password: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ email: null; password: null; }>'.
  Type '(prevState: { email: null; password: null; }) => { email: string; password: null; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { email: null; password: null; }) => { email: null; password: null; }'.
    Type '{ email: string; password: null; }' is not assignable to type '{ email: null; password: null; }'.
      Types of property 'email' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'. [2345]
(parameter) prevState: {
    email: null;
    password: null;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change null by empty string? I mean if you use `useState({email: "", password: ""})`?

Comment: @lomse that sorts it out, but as I mentioned in the question I want to figure out a way where `someType | null` approach is used i.e. if I use custom interfaces in the future but want initial values to be null or undefined

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Currently, the TypeScript compiler thinks the type of `email` and `password` are `null` (and no other value). You can resolve this by providing an explicit type parameter to the `useState` call so that the types of `email` and `password` are known to be `string` or `null`.

```
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<{email: null | string, password: null | string}>({ email: null, password: null });

  function setEmail(email: string) {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email }))
  }

  return <p>{state.email}</p>
}
```

Answer (score 34):

This is addressed in a few spots already:

https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-react-hooks-28j2

https://codewithstyle.info/Using-React-useState-hook-with-TypeScript/

TLDR: pass a type argument to setState when you have an empty initial state

eg:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
```

Comment: what about objects?

Comment: @refaelio Even for objects, if you keep the brackets empty it won't cause issue if you have a defined interface or type. For example, this works `const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>();` whereas this does not work `const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>(null);`

Answer (score 2):

you can use TS mapped types to improve readability and prefer undefined over null values

```
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Partial<{email: string, password: string}>>();

  function setEmail(email: string) {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email }))
  }

  return <p>{state.email | ""}</p>
}
```

Comment: I think you should comment/edit the accepted answer as your answer is not as readable and provides no additional benefits to the existing answer.

Comment: I think this solution is better considering it use less caracters : repeat `null | xxx`  four times doesn't improve readability ?

Comment: Having `null` properties and not having them at all is not the same.

Comment: Using a Partial is actually a good idea and helped me :)