# Assistance with React useState hook for temporarily empty/null data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks

Having some issues getting the useState() react hook to work with my implementation.

```
const [email, setEmail ] = useState<string>("");
```

```
<IonItem> 
  <IonLabel position={"stacked"}>Email</IonLabel> 
  <IonInput type={"email"} value={email} onIonChange={(event) => setEmail(event.detail.value)}/> </IonItem>
```

I keep getting the following error on the `setEmail(event.detail.value)`:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.

I am a bit confused as to why I am still getting this error?  I read on a previous post here on the answers to use the `useState<string>("");` implementation:

[Correct way to type nullable state when using React's useState hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338922/correct-way-to-type-nullable-state-when-using-reacts-usestate-hook)

Comment: `useState<string | null>("");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the type of your `useState` value as a string. However, the type of `event.detail.value` might be a string or it can be `null` or `undefined`. Since `setEmail` is a function that only accepts strings, and you try to assign a value that might `null` or `undefined` TS complains.

You can change the definition of the `useState` to include `undefined` and `null`:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState<string | undefined | null>("");
```

Or you can make sure that the stored value is always a string. Use the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), or the standard [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) if `??` is not supported to replace the `undefined` or `null` with an empty string.

```
onIonChange={(event) => setEmail(event.detail.value ?? '')}
```

Comment: Great way to fix the problem, but I think the question was more "why" this is happening as opposed to "how do I fix it".

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a suitable answer on how to fix this.

**Why is that happening?**
Because the inner function of `onIonChange` has declared (typescript) that possible return values are `null`, `undefined` or a `string`. Therefore you are forced to cast the value previously (e.g. `null` to empty string) or change the possible types of your state variable.